# Compare certain indices of many lists

Tags: python, list, indices

I have a list containing of lists containing of x- and y-coordinates:
`[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], … [xn, yn]]`.

I want the smallest and the largest x- and y-coordinates.

Since the x-coordinates are always at index 0, I want to compare all values at index 0 and find the min and the max. Same for index 1 (y-coordinates).

My solution right now:

```
listX = []
listY = []
for i in list:
    listX.append(i[0])
    listY.append(i[1])

xmin = min(listX)
xmax = max(listX)
ymin = min(listY)
ymax = max(listY)
```

Is there a better way? For example "Comparing all values at index 0 and find the min" in one line? In total this would be four lines instead of eight.

##### Context

I need this because I have a white image with not known shapes in it. For each shape I want to know the smallest rectangle there is to cover each shape completely. (4 shapes -> 4 rectangles not 1 rectangle for all). Different shapes can have the same color, but if that‘s the case they are not touching. Shapes of different colors could touch each other. The rectangles are allowed to overlap. This list in my question contains of all the pixels that are part of a certain shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly verbose, but you could use numpy to transpose the list so that all x values and y values are grouped in rows and then just get the min and max from each:

```
lst = [[1,2],[9,9],[2,2],[3,9]]

import numpy as np
def min_max(arr):
    lst = np.array(arr).transpose()
    min_x, max_x = np.min(lst[0]), np.max(lst[0])
    min_y, max_y= np.min(lst[1]), np.max(lst[1])
    return min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y

print(min_max(lst))
```

Outputs:

```
(1, 9, 2, 9)
```

---

Another way is to iterate over the list and keep track of the global min and max values:

```
lst = [[1,2],[9,9],[2,2],[3,9]]

def min_max2(arr):
    min_x = arr[0][0]
    min_y = arr[0][1]
    max_x = arr[0][0]
    max_y = arr[0][1]
    for x, y in arr:
        if x < min_x:
            min_x = x
        if y < min_y:
            min_y = y
        if x > max_x:
            max_x = x
        if y > max_y:
            max_y = y
    return min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y

print(min_max2(lst))
```

Outputs:

```
(1, 9, 2, 9)
```

Comment: I am new to Python and  I have to admit, that this is the only answer I understand completely so I will go with your function min-max(arr). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [key parameter](https://initialcommit.com/blog/python-min-function#using-the-optional-key-parameter) on min and max functions.

```
xmin = min(lst, key = lambda v: v[0])[0]  # use [0] since min returns [x, y] pair
ymin = min(lst, key = lambda v:v[1])[1]   # use [1] since max returns [x, y] pair 
xmax = max(lst, key = lambda v: v[0])[0]
ymax = max(lst, key = lambda v:v[1])[1]
```

Comment: `min` and `max` return terms of the same type of the list, hence tuple/list, so a further item selection is needed

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be decouple the list of pairs into list of xs and ys, order them and choose the 1st and last term.

```
coords = [(1, 2), (11, 15), (-4, 9)]

# decoupling
xs, ys = tuple(zip(*coords))

# get first and last term of a list with term in increasing order
x_min, x_max = sorted(xs)[::len(coords)-1]
y_min, y_max = sorted(ys)[::len(coords)-1]

# out
print(x_min, x_max)
print(y_min, y_max)
```

or simply using `sort` with the callback `key`

```
x_min, x_max = [x for x, _ in sorted(coords, key=lambda p: p[0])[::len(coords)-1]]
y_min, y_max = [y for _, y in sorted(coords, key=lambda p: p[1])[::len(coords)-1]]
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but I don‘t understand it, so I won‘t use it until I know what sou are doing there. I am new to Python, but maybe someday I will come back to your comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Agent00111 ! The idea behind both ways is the same: sort the list to infer an **order** on its items then choose the first and last term to get the minimum and the maximum (this is done with the slice `[::len(coords)-1]`).  Here the difference: in the 1st you have a list of numbers (due to the decoupling) in the second you have a list of points. So, for the second case `sort` returns a list of two points `[(xmin, _), (xmax, _)]` where `_` is a placeholder for smt that we don't care... and that's why is needed a further iteration to get the corresponding coordinate

Answer (score 1):

You could transform the list to a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
lst = [[5, 2], [8, 2], [3, 9], [1, 6]]
a = np.array(lst)
```

and either use [`np.amin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html) and `np.amax()`:

```
xmin, ymin = np.amin(a, axis=0)
xmax, ymax = np.amax(a, axis=0)
```

or slice the array and use `min()` and `max()`:

```
xmin = min(a[:,0])
xmax = max(a[:,0])
ymin = min(a[:,1])
ymax = max(a[:,1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple and compact solution.